# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException when retrieving Exception Message Property

Tags: exception, database-connection, sybase

When retrieve Exception Message Property, it throws an exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

I'm trying to execute query at Sybase using `AseConnection` but it threw an exception and I can't log this error because line `ex.Message` throws an exception also.

Please solve my issue with Sybase.

Code:

```
cmd.CommandText = sqlStatment;
            try
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }
                value = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                error = ex.Message;
            }
```